# Angular object returning reference variable instead of value unless called directly within the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, debugging

### Problem:

An object in the angular controller returns a reference variable instead of the value for the object property. When I call that property directly inside one of the controller's it returns correctly but when I do the same on the front end it returns the reference variable instead of the property value.

**Edit function of the Lot Controller**

```
this.edit = function(lotId){
    lotService.getById(lotId).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data[0]);
        console.log(response.data[0].Lot.id);
        lotService.broadcastSubLotChange(response.data[0]);
            ...
    });
}
```

**Edit function console logs**

[image: console logs]

*Notice the property value returned in the object is different than the value when called directly*

---

### ***Additional Information:***

**Lot Service broadcast function**

```
 this.broadcastSubLotChange = function(subLot){
        this.sublot=subLot;
    }
```

**Form Controller Broadcast Listener**

```
$scope.$on('sublotChange', function() {
        $scope.lot=lotService.sublot;
        if($scope.lot.Lot==null){
            $scope.lot={'Lot':{'parentLot':{'Lot':{'id':lotService.lot.Lot.id}}}};
        }   

        console.log(lotService.sublot);
        console.log("sublot: "+$scope.lot.Lot.id);
        console.log("lot: "+$scope.lot.Lot.parentLot.Lot.id); 
  });
```

**Form Controller Listener Logs**

[image: console logs]

**HTML call of angular variables**

- {{lot.Lot}} returns correctly other than "id":"{{lot.Lot.id}}"
- {{lot.Lot.parentLot.Lot.id}} returns correctly 755
- {{lot.Lot.id}} returns {{lot.Lot.id}}

Comment: This is all very weird. My best guess is this `id` property is overriden by the front-end as a plain string, when somewhere in your html you try to set it to "'{{lot.Lot.id}}'". And that weird behaviour with the object happens because it's evaluated at different time (later) than a directly logged property and by that time it gets overriden by the string from markup. Try commenting out html code and see the console logs again.

Comment: That was my first inclination and I tried that already, but after reading your response I dug a bit deeper.  I found the issue in a sperate controller. It appears that the the model's $scope.id was binded through the service layer, thus modifying it in one controller changed it in the other without having to broadcast it.  The problem code in the other controller: `<form:input  type="hidden" path="lot" ng-model="lot.Lot.id" value="{{lot.Lot.id}}" />` changed to: `<form:input  type="hidden" path="lot"  value="{{lot.Lot.id}}" />` Thanks for the help.